# Intermittent 502 errors on local nginx-ingress router in microk8s cluster

Tags: http, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, microk8s

I'm new to Kubernetes and am experiencing a weird issue with my nginx-ingress router. My cluster is run locally on a raspberry pi using Microk8s, where I have 4 different deployments. The cluster uses an ingress router to route packets for the UI and API.

In short, my issue is that I receive intermittent 502 errors on calls from the UI to the backend. Intermittent meaning that for every 3 successful POSTs, there are 3 unsuccessful 502 requests (regardless of how quickly these requests are called). E.g.,

[image]

I've applied the following Ingress configuration to my cluster:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-router
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ui
            port: 
              number: 80
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /lighting/.*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: api
            port: 
              number: 8000
```

And the deployments for UI and API are as follow:

- UI:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ui
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: iot-control-center
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: iot-control-center
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ui-container
          image: canadrian72/iot-control-center:ui
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

- API:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: iot-control-center
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: iot-control-center
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api-container
          image: canadrian72/iot-control-center:api
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
            - containerPort: 1883
```

After looking around online, I found this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/oa6rmh/ingress_showing_502_bad_gateway_error/) which most closely resembles my issue, although I'm not too sure where to go from here. I have a feeling it's a load issue for either the pods or the ingress controller, so I tried adding 3 replicas to each pod (it was 1 before), but this only decreased the frequency of 502 errors.

### Edit

It’s not necessarily 1 to one for 200 and 502 responses, it’s fairly random but about an even distribution of 502 and 200 responses. Also to add that I had configured this same setup with LoadBalancer (metallb) and everything worked like a charm, except for CORS. Which is why I went for Ingress to deal with CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving this up if anyone has a similar issue. My issue was that in the ingress configuration, the backend services referenced the deployments themselves instead of a nodeport/clusterIP service.

I instead created two cluster IP services for the UI and API, like follows:

- UI

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ui-cluster-ip
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: iot-control-center 
    svc: ui
  ports:
    - port: 80
```

- API

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: lighting-api-cluster-ip
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: iot-control-center
    svc: lighting-api
  ports:
    - port: 8000
```

And then referenced these services from the ingress yaml as follows:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-router
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin";
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST,
      OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: ui-cluster-ip
                port:
                  number: 80
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /lighting/.*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: lighting-api-cluster-ip
                port:
                  number: 8000
```

I'm not sure why the previous configuration posted resulted in some 503 responses and some 200 (in my mind it should've all been 503), but in any case this solution works.